# How to set an object inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two object maps;

```
var one = { '1': { id: 1, pid: 1, name: 'John'},
        '3': { id: 35, pid: 3, name: 'Josh'},
        '5': { id: 34, pid: 5, name: 'Joe'} }

var two = {1:1, 34:1, 35:1}

Object.keys(one).forEach(function(item){
    two[one[item].id]= {pid : one[item]};
});
```

I want result as

```
{1:  { '1': { id: 1, pid: 1, name: 'John'}, 34: {'3': { id: 34, pid: 3, name: 'Josh'}}, 35:{'5': { id: 35, pid: 5, name: 'Joe'}}}
```

But I'm getting

```
 {1:  { pid: { id: 1, pid: 1, name: 'John'}, 34: {pid: { id: 34, pid: 3, name: 'Josh'}}, pid:{'5': { id: 35, pid: 5, name: 'Joe'}}}
```

But i'm not getting dynamic pid , only stack pids. I know above loop sets it in static id, want to solve it to get dynamic pid.

Comment: Please post what are you getting also, might be helpful

Comment: If you format the object literals in your question and make them readable, you will see they are malformed.

Comment: Sorry I just want to make sure, I think you have misplaced 2nd and 3rd object in your expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the good result, just set the "pid" as a key like you did for the "id":

```
var one = { '1': { id: 1, pid: 1, name: 'John'},
        '3': { id: 35, pid: 3, name: 'Josh'},
        '5': { id: 34, pid: 5, name: 'Joe'} }

var two = {}

Object.keys(one).forEach(function(item){
    var current = one[item]
    // We initialize empty object
    two[current.id]= {}
     // We set the object at key .pid to what is wanted
    two[current.id][current.pid] = current
})

console.log(two)
```

Result (in JSON):

```
{"1":{"1":{"id":1,"pid":1,"name":"John"}},"34":{"5":{"id":34,"pid":5,"name":"Joe"}},"35":{"3":{"id":35,"pid":3,"name":"Josh"}}}
```

Comment: works as expected but I'm getting the whole things twice, just as expected but twice.

Comment: What do you mean twice? I'm getting it only once on my side (tested the code on chrome console directly) ! Might be a double console.log?

Comment: sorry my bad, had consoled it twice.Thanks a bunch. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you said you want isn't a valid object. My guess is that you want

```
var one = {
    1: { id: 1, pid: 1, name: 'John'},
    3: { id: 35, pid: 3, name: 'Josh'},
    5: { id: 34, pid: 5, name: 'Joe'}
}, two = {};
Object.keys(one).forEach(function(item){
    two[one[item].id]= one[item];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var one = { 
    '1': { id: 1, pid: 1, name: 'John'},
    '3': { id: 35, pid: 3, name: 'Josh'},
    '5': { id: 34, pid: 5, name: 'Joe'} 
}

var two = {1:1, 34:1, 35:1}

Object.keys(one).forEach(function(item){
    var obj = {};
    obj[one[item].pid] = one[item];
    two[one[item].id]= obj;
});

console.log (two);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
var one = { '1': { id: 1, pid: 1, name: 'John'},
    '3': { id: 35, pid: 3, name: 'Josh'},
    '5': { id: 34, pid: 5, name: 'Joe'} };

var two = {1:1, 34:1, 35:1};

for (key in one){
   var item = one[key];
   two[item.id] = {};
   two[item.id][item.pid] = item;
}
```